# PropelORM and database structure

Tags: php, mysql, orm, propel, polymorphic-associations

I need to decide which approach to choose for my MySQL DB.

Example:

```
PHOTO ALBUM 
User - can own photoalbum 
Group - can own photoalbum 
(maybe more entities could own photoalbum)
```

Now how to represent this in DB so it will:
Work nicely with Propel (join selects etc.)

I believe one approach is called polymorphic associations. But it has its own problem and I cannot find any resource talking about polymorphic associations with propel.

Second approach would be to represent everything separated. Meaning group_photoalbum user_photoalbum. It would be cleaner in MySQL and there will be no problem with Propel, but it would double most of the code and therefore any changes will be done twice.

Can Propel work with polymorphic associations? (any source)
Is there any other approach I don't know about? 
Which would you choose?

Comment: We're using EAV http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Propel inheritance. Should have read the docs whole.
[propel inheritance](http://propelorm.org/Propel/documentation/09-inheritance.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
Propel does not support polymorphic relationships.
```

You are best off using another ORM, if possible.
I mean, who uses XML 2018.

@Turnadiev Nursultan, he asked whether they support the relationship,
not if you can hack your way(which is a hack).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18747716)

Comment: I quote the gentleman asking the question,
"Can Propel work with polymorphic associations?"
There is a difference between you not understanding the answer and the answer itself not being clarified enough.